# I need to add 3 columns with counts of 3 values in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and each row has a unique ID but more than one entry for the unique ID based on customer survey score.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['store1', 'High'], ['store1', 'Medium'], ['store2', 'Low'], ['store2', 'Low']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Shop', 'Review'])
```

What I need to do is to create three new columns for High, Medium and Low and put the total High, medium, low received for each store to remove the multiple entries per store in the dataframe.

Comment: what is your desired output? provide desired output of input example in text table.

Comment: Something like this? https://onecompiler.com/python/426ngv7mq

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab) for this. To get the columns in the order `'High', 'Medium', 'Low'`, probably best to make the data in `df['Review']` categorical first ([`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)).

```py
df['Review'] = pd.Categorical(df['Review'], categories=['High', 'Medium', 'Low'])

out = pd.crosstab(df['Shop'], df['Review'])
out

Review  High  Medium  Low
Shop                     
store1     1       1    0
store2     0       0    2
```

If you do not like the names for the axes (i.e., "Shop" and "Review"), you can chain [`df.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to delete them:

```py
out = pd.crosstab(df['Shop'], df['Review']).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
out

        High  Medium  Low
store1     1       1    0
store2     0       0    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary for the reviews, and loop the data setting the values accordingly:

```
   data = [['store1', 'High'], ['store1', 'Medium'], ['store2', 'Low'], ['store2', 'Low']]
   reviews_dict = defaultdict(lambda: {'Low': 0, 'Medium': 0, 'High': 0})
   for entry in data:
       reviews_dict[entry[0]][entry[1]] += 1
```

After that just get the keys and the values and add it in the DataFrame.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(parsed_data.values()), index=parsed_data.keys(),
                  columns=['Low', 'Medium', 'High']).reset_index()

    df.rename(columns={'index': 'Shop'}, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
    print(df)

    ===================================
       Shop  Low  Medium  High
  0  store1    0       1     1
  1  store2    2       0     0
```